# How to get a class name given that self could be a class or an instance?

Tags: ruby

I have a module that provides logging functionality. Some classes `extend` it, others `include` it. As part of the logging, I pass in a class name.

If I do this:

```
global_logger.call(level, self, msg)
```

It could log either:

```
WARN -- Some::Class: some msg
```

OR

```
WARN -- #<Some::OtherClass:0x00007fdc04907710>: some msg
```

based on if the module was extended or included. I can call `self.class` instead, but then the the other one turns into `Class`.

Is there a way to get a class name(without the `#<...:0x00007fdc04907710>`), given that you don't know if `self` is a class or an instance?

Comment: How would you tell class messages from instance messages if they look the same?

Comment: @Stefan Whether the logs come from a class or an instance doesn't really matter, they're both ultimately just a caller of the `log` method, so the code logs the message, along with a tag of where that was called from.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you could do, but one of the easiest is probably to see if the passed object is a class before trying to extract other information about it. For example:

```
Object.kind_of? Class #=> true
Object.new.kind_of? Class #=> false
```

You can then decide what methods are appropriate to call based on whether or not it's a class. For example:

```
p Object.new.class.name #=> "Object"
P Object.name #=> "Object"
```

Answer (score 0):

We know that, for a given module `M`, you can determine if a class `C` has included `M` by writing

```
C.included_modules.include?(M)
```

To determine if a class `C` has extended `M` you may execute

```
C.singleton_class.included_modules.include?(M)
```

because extending a module to a class is equivalent to including the same module to the class' singleton class.

See [Module#included_modules](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-included_modules) and [Object#singleton_class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class).

Here is an example.

```
module M
  def m; end
end
```

```
class C
  extend M
end
```

```
a = C.singleton_class.included_modules
  #=> [M, Kernel] 
a.include?(M)
  #=> true
```